# Custom form in Django shows ids instead of string

Tags: python, django

guys! I'm struggling with django forms. Default ones represent models as expected (returning __ str __  values). However, my custom form (Event_form_for_Admin) shows ids instead of string in admin panel and on the site. What am I missing?

**models.py**

```
class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=800)    
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.level} {self.name}'


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model): 
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)    
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
  
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.action} {self.position}'
```

**forms.py**

```
class Event_form_for_Admin(forms.ModelForm):
    person = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label='Name')
    position = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label='Position')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['person','position']
```

**output on site as well as in admin panel:**

[image]

Comment: Why are you using CharFields with TextInputs? The model fields are ForeignKeys so the default  is a ModelChoiceField that generates a dropdown/select, why do you want to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your custom fields from custom form. Let Django do that work :)

```
class Event_form_for_Admin(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['person','position']
```